# Is asyncio.wait order guaranteed?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to implement fair queuing in my library that is based on asyncio.

In some function, I have a statement like (assume `socketX` are tasks):

```
done, pending = asyncio.wait(
    [socket1, socket2, socket3],
    return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED,
)
```

Now I read the documentation for [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) many times but it does not contain the information I'm after. Mainly, I'd like to know if:

- `socket1`, `socket2` and `socket3` happened to be already ready when I issue the call. Is it guaranteed that `done` will contain them all or could it be that it returns only one (or two) ?
- In the second case, does the order of the tasks passed to `wait()` matter ?

I'm trying to assert if I can just apply fair-queuing in the set of `done` tasks (by picking one and leaving the other tasks for later resolution) or if I also need to care about the order I pass the tasks in.

The documentation is kinda silent about this. Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only taken according to the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#l402) of Python 3.5.

If the future is done before calling `wait`, they will all be placed in the `done` set:

```
import asyncio

async def f(n):
    return n

async def main():
    (done, pending) = await asyncio.wait([f(1), f(2), f(3)], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    print(done)     # prints set of 3 futures
    print(pending)  # prints empty set

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Comment: I also tried that out but it didn't occur to me to check Python's source code. Not enough sleep I guess.Thanks a lot for trying it on your side. I guess what we can conclude is that there is no guarantee that it will always behave like that but that the current implementation does so on all platforms.